# How do I set the position of the addButton?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

The default added button is always at the end of the toolbar.
How do I set the position of the addButton?
And not at the end of the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify button ordering in TinyMCE with the `toolbar` configuration option.

For example, the following config will add the custom button before the bold button:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#editor',
  toolbar: 'myCustomToolbarButton bold',
  setup: (editor) => {
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('myCustomToolbarButton', {
      text: 'My Custom Button',
      onAction: () => alert('Button clicked!')
    });
  }
});
```